# LINQ Null Join with Pivot Table

Tags: c#, linq, null, left-join, pivot-table

I'm trying to get a list of servers thay may or may not belong to 1 or more groups to display in a grid.

Example

```
ServerID       IP            GroupID
    1      192.168.1.44      1
    1      192.168.1.44      10
    2      192.168.1.45      1
    3      192.168.1.46      2
    4      192.168.1.47      null
    5      192.168.1.48      null
```

If I have no records In the GroupServer Table. (Since there is no groups or groups exist but they are not assigned) I expect to get something like this:

```
 ServerID       IP               GroupID
        1    192.168.1.44      null
        2    192.168.1.45      null
        3    192.168.1.46      null
        4    192.168.1.47      null
        5    192.168.1.48      null
```

Since is a Many-to-Many relationship. I have

1. Group Table
2. Server Table
3. GroupServer Table

I could not find a LINQ Pivot Table example.
So I tried to buid my own.

```
  var query = (from sg in context.ServerGroups
                        join servers in context.Servers on sg.ServerID equals servers.ID
                        join groups in context.Groups on sg.GroupID equals groups.ID
                       into serverxgroup
                       from gAddrBilling in serverxgroup.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                       select new
                       {
                           ServerID = sg.ServerID,
                           ServerIP = server.IP,
                           GroupID =  sg.GroupID
                       });
```

The Query above does not retrieve anything
And I quiet dont understand what the "from gAddrBilling" is for. Since I modify a snippet I was trying to make work. So I wonder if someone has already faced a problem like this and give me some hint, snippet or advice about what is what I'm missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not a pivot query, but a regular query on many-to-may relationship via explicit junction table.

Second, looks like you are using Entity Framework, in which case you'd better define and use **navigation properties** rather than manual `join`s.

Third, and the most important, the structure of the query is wrong. If you want to *get a list of servers that may or may not belong to 1 or more groups*, then you should start your query from `Servers` (the table which records you want to be always included, not from link table where some `ServerID` are missing) and then use [left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_2)s to the other tables like this:

```
var query =
    from s in servers in context.Servers
    join sg in context.ServerGroups on s.ID equals sg.ServerID
    into s_sg from sg in s_sg.DefaultIfEmpty() // make the above LEFT OUTER JOIN
    // You can remove the next two lines if all you need is the GroupId
    // and keep them if you need some other Group field in the select
    join g in context.Groups on sg.GroupID equals g.ID
    into sg_g from g in sg_g.DefaultIfEmpty() // make the above LEFT OUTER JOIN
    select new
    {
        ServerID = s.ID,
        ServerIP = s.IP, // or sg.IP?
        GroupID =  (int?)sg.GroupID
    };
```

Comment: After some research I found out that the problem is a big bug in EF7 not doing the Left Joins properly.  
But Thank you so much for helping me.  And thanks for clearing that the term is junction table and not pivot table I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ah, EF Core and left joins, no more explanations needed :(